# Java 8 Streams. Pass Two arguments to a method called in forEach

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using Java 8 streams API, I want a way to call a reference method which accepts two arguments. `splitFileByMaxRows` is the reference method that should take a `String` and an `int` as its arguments. Is there any way to achieve it?

```
private void breakLargeFileIntoChunks(final File setlFile, int parentFileId) {
    LOG.info(LOG.isInfoEnabled() ? "*** Breaking Large File Into Chunks ***" : null);

    try (Chunker chunker = new Chunker(); 
         Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(setlFile.getAbsolutePath()))) {
        lines.forEach(chunker::splitFileByMaxRows);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can't use a method reference, since you have no way of passing the `int` argument to it.

Therefore, use a lambda expression instead:

```
lines.forEach(s -> chunker.splitFileByMaxRows(s,someInt));
```

Answer (score 0):

A MethodReference can be used only in the place where a Consumer is allowed. If you recollect a Consumer takes in only one input parameter. So in your case you have two arguments, this is not possible to be passed in as Method reference to a consumer. So you have to use a lambda that can take arguments as necesssary.